# Getting coverage using OpenCover for Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, code-coverage, opencover

The background:
We have a project starting a service that gets controlled from the web interface GUI. 
We're not using a specific (from a commercial point of view) web server, but an in-house created wrapper around the windows service that manages all the web interface interactions.

What we have:
Now we've started using Selenium & MSTest for testing the web interface and we're trying to get a coverage for these kind of tests, and OpenCover seemed to do the deal. The problem is that is not (or we're doing something different or wrong).
The only code coverage that I'm not getting is the one for the method used to start the windows service and all others that get called in the process (since I have all access to all the PDBs too), but afterwards nothing is covered, based on the action that take place from the Selenium's interaction with the browser.

Any hints/ideas or maybe other tools that are able to do the job (if even possible) are appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

If you're running an ASP.net app, you're going to need to attach OpenCover to IIS or IISExpress to get accurate code coverage with selenium. That makes it a little hard to use MSTest with. You may want to consider moving as much logic into your services, and write unit tests against those.

Here's a quick example hot to attach open cover to IIS
OpenCover.Console.exe -target:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -targetargs:-debug 
-targetdir:C:\Inetpub\wwwwoot\MyWebApp\bin\ -filter:+[] -register:user